# Import and create a hexdump view of file

Tags: import, files-and-directories, binary

How would I go about creating a hexdump type of view of an imported binary file?
for example, (format is

`<file offset> | <hex contents> | <ascii representation>`)

[image]

Which I could then perform an analysis on top of.

*UPDATE*

I have gotten pretty close with the following

```
hexdata = ReadByteArray["..file"];


hexshowAmount = 80;
hex = (hexdata[[1 ;; hexshowAmount]] // Normal);

tbl = hex // Partition[#, UpTo@16] &;
nrows = Length@tbl;
ncols = Length@tbl[[1]];

myFunc[val_] := PrimeQ[val]; (* Must Return True or False *)

labels = Flatten@
  Table[If[myFunc[tbl[[i]][[j]]], {i, j} -> Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9],
     Nothing], {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}];

tbl // Grid[Map[BaseForm[#, 16] &, #, {2}], Frame -> All, 
   Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
   Background -> {None, None, labels}, ItemSize -> {2, 2}] &
```

Open for improvements though.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
ba = BinaryReadList["file", "UnsignedInteger16"];
baHex = IntegerString[#, 16] & /@ ba

Multicolumn[baHex, Sequence[16, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]]
```

Comment: Ah well for my computer I need to use `"UnsignedInteger8"` (unless you intended for the 2 byte groupings--however this returns the hexdump 2 bytes at a time in a little endian interpretation and not as a raw byte). In any case `ReadByteArray` works for this portion of the question.

Comment: @skyfire The `hexdump` image in the question is for 2 bytes, so I assumed that is what was wanted.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to comment on how doing so in this way interprets reinterprets the bytes as in little endian. i.e. each of the 2 bytes read in is being read as a "short" in C language lingo. This is not the same as the ordering of bytes as they occur within the file. Every 2 bytes will be swapped with how they occur within the file.